# Table doesn't fit in parent div

Tags: html, css

Here is an example of what I am trying to do(put a table in a div and make it fill the div): [ex1_jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ph3ban0v)

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 55px 0px 55px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
tr {
  margin-top: 0;
}
aside {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: solid 2px;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
}
#table_div {
  float: left;
  border: solid 2px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  width: 700px;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<aside>sidebar</aside>
<div id="table_div">
  <table>
    
    <tr>
      
      <th>Firstname</th>
      
      <th>Lastname</th>
      
      <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The problem is that as you see in `ex1` the table is getting out of the parent div. And the most strange thing is that if I indent the elements between `<div_id="table_div>` and `</div>` with 1 tab, it works BUT ONLY in jsfiddle: [ex2_jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6d52c67r/)

When I try it in my browser(Chrome) it doesn't work.

So, can someone explain to me what is going on?

Comment: I just loaded it locally using Chrome and it looks like this: http://imgur.com/0D6cAdN

Comment: Have you tried setting `overflow:auto;` on the parent div?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have some   characters there. They seem harmeless spaces, but in fact they are [non-breaking spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (`&nbsp;`), which HTML does not consider [space characters](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#space-character).

```
<div>IT WORKS!</div>

<aside>sidebar</aside>
<div id="table_div">
<table >
&nbsp; <tr>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <th>Firstname</th>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <th>Lastname</th>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <th>Age</th>
&nbsp; </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

These `&nbsp;` are not allowed there, so the parser moves them before the table. This produces that empty line.

Comment: how did you notice them? I am using Netbeans and I copied the table code from w3 schools, but it shows them as normal space. How can I see them as `&nbsp`?

Comment: @CuriousGuy Code on websites is often contaminated in that way, formatted for visually pleasing display rather than copyability.

Comment: @CuriousGuy Yes, it's difficult to notice. Especially because Firefox converts non-breaking spaces to spaces when you copy. I noticed them because I selected the output and used "View selected source", which displayed `&nbsp;` before the table. To know where exactly they were in the source, I opened the console and used `document.getElementById('id_code_html').value.split('\u00a0').join('&nbsp;')`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in JSfiddle, the "tab-less" version (ex1_jsfiddle) register a character in between `<div>` and `<table>` and hence, pushing the table down.

I try it in chrome and it exactly looks like what @zer00ne comment. But when I put an empty character e.g. `&nbsp`, it looks like your ex1_jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution!
please change '#talbd_div' width to %

```
#table_div {
  float: left;
  border: solid 2px;
  padding-left: 15%;
  height: 300px;
  width: 80%;
  border-color: red;
}
```